# EditText é apagado quando uso setSelection() dentro do método onTextChanged

Tags: android, edittext

Estou tentando colocar uma máscara de telefone pelo método `onTextChanged`, o texto recebido nesse método está vindo ao contrário, e quando tento colocar o método `setSelection`() para que o cursor posicione no final, meu `EditText` é apagado, no Galaxy Tab 10. Como resolver isso?

```
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcherTelefone = new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            try {
                if (atualizando) {
                    atualizando = false;
                    return;
                }


                String resultado = limparFormatacaoNumero(s.toString());

                if (isNumero(resultado)) {

                    if (resultado.length() <= 14) {
                        resultado = adicionarFormatacaoTelefone(resultado);

                    } else {
                        resultado = resultado.substring(0, 14);
                        resultado = adicionarFormatacaoTelefone(resultado);
                    }
                    atualizando = true;
                    textoDiscagem.setText(resultado);
                    textoDiscagem.setSelection(textoDiscagem.getText().length());

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Já chegou a testar o `PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher`? Dá uma olhada na documentação para ver como configurar ele: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.html.

Answer (score 1):

Uma ótima solução seria a implementação de uma classe já do Android, o [PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.html):

```
PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher mPhoneWatcher = new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher();       
etPhone.addTextChangedListener(mPhoneWatcher);
```

**Apenas um detalhe sobre essa classe**

Ela utiliza como padrão o `Locale` padrão, ou seja, se o aparelho do usuário estiver em inglês, o número formatado será em inglês.

Na documentação acima, está dizendo que aceita o construtor `PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher(String countryCode)`, porém, se abrirmos o javadoc esse construtor possuí uma tag `@hide`, ou seja, não está disponível no SDK para utilizarmos.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema colocando no EditText via xml a tag:

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
```

descobri que o problema estava no auto-completar.